# firefox form not working when cursor:move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML form like

```css
    #stoppage_section .stoppage{
        cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
        cursor: grab;
        cursor: -moz-grab;
        cursor: -webkit-grab;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="stoppage_section">
      <div class="stoppage">
         <input class="form-control" ....>
      </div>
      <div class="stoppage">
         <input class="form-control" ....>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to show cursor like `move` icon when user move around this `stoppage_section` area. BUT when mouse will come over into input fields then it work as normal.

This code working fine in Chrome. **BUT in firefox input fields not writable anymore**

## What I want

When mouse(cursor) will be in `div` then it will show `move` icon and when mouse(cursor) will be in input fields it will work as normal

> Mozilla Firefox Version 48.0.2. Latest version not possible to use for
>   me as Firebug looks like native style which is disgusting

Comment: It is working completely on my Mozilla which version are you using?

Comment: Your snippet does not reproduce the issue for me either. (Firefox 50.1.0, Win 10)

Comment: The cursor doesn't change anyway... Did you want a hover effect?

Comment: try adding text between div and input because there is no space between your div and input cursor is not going to shown up

Comment: working perfect with me!

Comment: I have edited my question for mozilla version @HirenJungi

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
    .stoppage {
        background-color: #dddddd; /* that you can see the div */
    }

    .stoppage:hover {
        cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
        cursor: grab;
        cursor: -moz-grab;
        cursor: -webkit-grab;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="stoppage_section">
      <div class="stoppage">
         <input class="form-control" ....>
      </div>
      <div class="stoppage">
         <input class="form-control" ....>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hover over text and outside input text in same line you might see hand cursor.

```css
    #stoppage_section .stoppage{
        cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
        cursor: grab;
        cursor: -moz-grab;
        cursor: -webkit-grab;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="stoppage_section">
      <div class="stoppage">
         Input Text
         <input class="form-control" ....>
      </div>
      <div class="stoppage">
         Input Text
         <input class="form-control" ....>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what you trying to say, not helped

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine with me. Still if you want fallback for Mozilla you can just add the below style with your existing style:

```
.stoppage input:hover {
    cursor: edit; //on hovering input box show edit cursor
        }
```